# Android logo hangup

Tags: boot-loop, system-freeze

Anybody knows how to fix this problem? I have a tablet probably made in China. It always hanging up in android logo with the black background and didn't enter to the OS desktop. The store where we bought this tablet provided us a firmware that will reinstall the android to the tablet again. It will fix the hang up but when I turn off the tab and on it again the hang up still occur.

Is there any software available that will fix this?

The tab model is FP-024-m

Comment: Have you tried a [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) already? Or a boot into [safe mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info)?

Comment: Yes I did factory reset, but doing that will not fix the hang up. You really need to do the firmware. But I don't know how to go in safe mode. Every tablet model has its different command to do that I think.

Comment: If a factory-reset didn't solve it, safe-mode won't help either. If the fresh ROM also only temporarily solves it, I'd return the device for replacement.